# MPI asynchronous sending

Tags: asynchronous, mpi, nonblocking

I need asynchronous message sending. I read about non-blocking sending on MPI (e.g. MPI_Isend or MPI_Ibcast) and functions to wait/test that sending request (MPI_Wait*/MPI_Test*). However I realize (through testing and web info) that non-blocking send might never get progress on receiver unless that sender invokes functions MPI_Wait*/MPI_Test* after it sends. How can I get a real (and optimal) asynchronous sending?

Regards

Comment: you need to use a MPI library that features a progress thread (a recent Open MPI should do the trick on most interconnects, at least for point-to-point operations). Not quite sure of what you mean by "optimal" ... a progress thread has some kind of overhead with respect to message latency, even if Open MPI does its best to keep it minimal (and sometimes even un-noticeable)

Comment: Hello @Gilles Gouaillardet. Thank you for your answer. I'm using Open MPI 4.0.1 (latest is 4.0.2). Indeed, with "optimal" I was referring to that: overhead.
Respect to the main thing, I'm newbie in MPI: can you explain me a little more about "progress thread" approach? Maybe with some very general example about it. I will really appreciate. Regards.

Comment: a progress thread is an internal and optional MPI feature to ensure that communications progress (e.g. `MPI_Isend()` will eventually send the message) even if no MPI subroutine is invoked by the application. Which interconnect are you using?

Comment: @Gilles I don't know if I correctly understood your question. If It was what functions I'm using, they are: MPI_Isend on sender and receiver (but here, on receiver, blocking, i.e. followed by a MPI_Wait). Nevertheless I will need to use MPI_Ibcast on sender too. I don't know if this answer your question. Regards

Comment: did you ask the same question on the Open MPI mailing list ?

Comment: Yes @Gilles, I did it. I didn't figure out how to handle that suggestion, but now I do. I'm starting to work on it. I will let you know the results. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @GillesGouaillardet this works for me. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Lutret Would you mind giving me some insight on how you solved the "progress thread" issue?